# after closing the iAd banner my view remain in landscape mode but my app supports portrait only

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, orientation, iad

i am implementing iAd banner in my iPad application it loads fine, but when i am tapping on it, it changes my app orientation to landscape and after closing the add it remain in landscape mode, i should this in portrait orentation. how can i solve this issue i am using iOS 7 sdks

[image: view in portrait]

[image: after closing the iAd banner]

Here is my code

```
#pragma mark - AdBannerViewDelegate method implementation

-(void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
NSLog(@"Ad Banner will load ad.");
}


-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
NSLog(@"Ad Banner did load ad.");

// Show the ad banner.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.adBanner.alpha = 1.0;
}];
}


-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{
NSLog(@"Ad Banner action is about to begin.");

//    self.pauseTimeCounting = YES;

return YES;
}


-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
NSLog(@"Ad Banner action did finish");


//    self.pauseTimeCounting = NO;
}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Unable to show ads. Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

// Hide the ad banner.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.adBanner.alpha = 0.0;
}];
}
```